# Terraform command and not gcp api call to get state lock id from remote backend

Tags: terraform, gcloud

Is there a way to find the lock ID associated with a Terraform state configuration by using terraform command and not gcp or aws api.

I can get it when I call "terrafrom plan" for project with locked state but "terraform plan" takes bit time.

Command "terraform state list" does not show lock id next to locked resources, it only shows list of resources in state.